# Color cell from mat table angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I've got this:

Array of objects:

```
  users : User [];
  average = 5;


compareValue (value){
...}
```

And im printing a table: like this:

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="users">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="nome">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" > {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="num_aval">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Number of Works</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.works.length}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="comparaMedia">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Stats</th>
        <td  *matCellDef="let element" > HELP HERE </td>
      </ng-container>


    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

  </table>
```

What I wanna do is the following:

I wanna grab the number of works from an user, compare with the value average (with the function **compareValue**), and **if the value is under some value, color the cell with blue; if it's above, color the cell with red.**

I have no ideia how to do it. Some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `compareValue` func returns true if value in cell is higher than average and false when it isn't, so I would use 
 and than use it to setting background color for number of works value cell

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" 
  [style.background-color]="compareValue(element.works.length) ? 'blue' : 'red'"> 
{{element.works.length}} 
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class conditionally to your `td` as

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [class.red]="element.works.length > average"> {{element.works.length}} </td>
```

And add styles to your component as

```
td {
    background-color: blue; /* the default color is blue for the cells */
}

td.red {
    background-color: red; /* more specific style to override color to red */
}
```

Comment: so when values equal it's still blue, what isn't mentioned in the question, another thing is that he wants to compare it with average not hardcoded 5, but still I think your answer is more simple than mine so i will vote it up

Comment: @Jake11 I have changed the code to compare with `average`. I see that even you are assigning `background-color` between blue and red